# How can I track the frame rate on a mobile device?

Tags: iphone, frame-rate

I am trying to track the frame rate when performaing certain actions on my mobile device.

Scenario: I open my game via the device browser and run through specific actions.
Preferably would like the frame rate stored somewhere, like a text file. Would settle for visual display if that is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since you apparently don't want this for the end user, I'd suggest just running with the performance monitor.

With your device connected try running:

`Run -> Run With Performance Tool -> OpenGL ES.`

That'll give you Core Animation FPS, but also loads of other stats about your application, which is probably more helpful to you if you're trying to assess performance issues.